# Cross domain access between the servers in same intranet

Tags: javascript

I have two different servers (IBM WAS 7 and Tomcat 7 ) both inside the intranet, Application A is deployed on the WAS and Application B on the Tomcat , User invokes the application A and click on a link that opens up the new window which has the url for application B deployed on tomcat, the application opens up correctly in the new window, but when I try to get the handle of the parent window from a page in the application B (using whose link I opened up the application B in the new window), It gives me the error that Access is Denied / Permission is Denied. Both servers are the part of the same Intranet, Is there any way to get hold of the parent application A window, so that I can invoke some javascript functions exposed by Application A.

Comment: You should probably post some code in regards to what you're doing here: "but when I try to get the handle of the parent window from a page in the application B"

Comment: I am using window.opener   try{
  if(window.opener!=null){
   window.opener.document.focus();
   window.opener.clientAPI.myFunction(id);
   }
  }catch(exp){alert(exp.message)};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The underlying network topology has no effect on Javascript security.  For example, "localhost" and "127.0.0.1" are two unrelated domains to Javascript.

The Javascript interpreters on two different windows can communicate via [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage).

Comment: Thanks for the response ,  I tried the postMessage, but it only works for iframes in IE8+ , So I created an iframe inside the page in application B, with the source url of application A, and posting the message from the application B to this iframe, but the contents of the original application window A are not accepting the message but I can see the message received in the iframe holding the application A, is there any way the original window having application A can receive the message.

Comment: First of all, friends don't let friends use IE.  But if you must, B can talk through postMessage to an iframe in domain A that it contains.  That iframe can talk to another window in domain A *if it created that window*.  So, that is the trick.  B creates an iframe and that iframe calls `window.open`.

Comment: Thanks Malvolio, I am able to get a fresh page in the iframe in B to refer to the parent window in frame A using the reference window.parent.opener

Comment: Ah.  You might want to use `window.top.opener`, in case you end up deeper than you planned.